# How can abiFilters result in ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android, classnotfoundexception, abi, huawei-mobile-services

Currently I am trying to add Huawei standard widgets to a launcher app that has `abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "armeabi", "mips"` in build.gradle file (without filters I get `UnsatisfiedLinkError` with another library).

This results in:

> Error inflating class com.huawei.android.totemweather.widget.WeatherSimpleWidgetView Exception is Didn't find class "com.huawei.android.totemweather.widget.WeatherSimpleWidgetView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/priv-app/HwWeatherClock/HwWeatherClock.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/priv-app/HwWeatherClock/lib/arm64, /system/priv-app/HwWeatherClock/HwWeatherClock.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]`

and:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.huawei.android.totemweather.widget.WeatherSimpleWidgetView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/MY_PACKAGE_NAME-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/MY_PACKAGE_NAME-1/lib/arm, /data/app/MY_PACKAGE_NAME-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]

If I remove abiFilters everything works out fine. How can a filter that is meant for `.so` files result in missing classes?